# Crear login a cada modelo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Soy nuevo en rails. La duda es la siguiente. Tengo tres modelos, cliente, vendedor y  users generado con devise. Cómo puedo asignar un login a cada vendedor y cliente al crear uno nuevo?

Answer (score 1):

Una opción puede ser que a user le asignes un atributo `user_type`. En tus formas, cuando crees un usuario, puedes especificar si es un `cliente` o `vendedor`.

Para agregar el atributo a tu modelo User:

```
rake generate migration AddUserTypeToUsers user_type:string:index
```

Y luego correr la migración:

```
rake db:migrate
```

En tu modelo User, para obtener solo los vendedores o clientes:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  scope :vendedores, -> { where(user_type: "vendedor") }
  scope :clientes, -> { where(user_type: "cliente) }
end
```

En tu forma, puedes tener un `hidden_field` asignando `vendedor` o `cliente`, segun sea el caso, sin embargo, alguien podría manipular ese campo oculto y decir que es vendedor desde la forma en lugar de cliente. También podrías pasarlo en los params.

Ahora, podrás obtener a los clientes via `User.clientes` y a los vendedores via `User.vendedores`.

Finalmente, con este tipo de solución, tanto tus clientes como vendedores son usuarios, ya será parte de tu aplicación asignarles diferentes funciones y capacidades a cada una.

Por favor, avísame si tienes dudas sobre como implementar este código.

> Nota: Para crear y correr la migración, puedes utilizar el comando `rails` en lugar de `rake` a partir de la versión 5 de Ruby on Rails.

**Actualización**

Una opción para que `Vendedor` tenga diferentes atributos que `Cliente` es que asocies los modelos `User`, con `Vendedor` y `Cliente`, de tal forma que `User` tenga todas las características en común y los otros modelos las particulares.

Para realizar esto habría que completar lo siguiente:

> Asumiendo que ya tienes los modelos `Vendedor` y `Cliente`

1) Asociar el modelo `User` con un vendedor o cliente

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :vendedor
  has_one :cliente
end
```

2) Asociar el modelo `Vendedor` con un el `User`

```
class Vendedor < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

3) Asociar el modelo `Cliente` con un el `User`

```
class Cliente < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

4) Asociar los modelos en la base de datos

4.1) Crear la migración para asociar `Vendedor` con `User`

```
rake generate migration AddUserIdToVendedores user:references
```

4.2) Crear la migración para asociar `Cliente` con `User`

```
rake generate migration AddUserIdToClientes user:references
```

4.3) Correr las migraciones (primero revisa los archivos creados para estar seguros de que todo esté como es debido). Si al correr las migraciones tuvieras errores, una razón podría ser que estén equivocados los nombres de las tablas "Vendedores" o "Clientes". Tu migración debe estar modificando la tabla, tal y como se llame en el archivo `config/schema.rb`.

```
rake db:migrate
```

Este código produce que todos sean usuarios, cada usuario está asociado con un "tipo de usuario", ya sea vendedor o cliente. Ahora, cuando quieras vendedores, puedes llamarlos como `Vendedores.all` y los clientes como `Clientes.all`.

Como repaso general, una instancia de `Vendedor` sólo tendrá lo especifico del vendedor y el user_id, por lo que puedes saber a que usuario corresponde.

Ahora, puedes utilizar el generador que incluye devise para personalizar las vistas(`rails generate devise:views users`), tomar el código que necesites para crear cuentas (sign up) y tener dos formas, una para clientes y otra para vendedores. Deberás tener también tus respectivos controladores para cada modelo.

No probé este código, es decir lo estoy escribiendo directamente en el campo de la respuesta, así que si encuentras un error, por favor dime para corregirlo.

Comment: con este método puedo crear las cuentas de cliente y vendedor por medio del registra del user, pero en el caso de que el cliente y vendedor no compartan la misma información ¿como se podría crear el login? ¿tendria que que llamar los campos de user dentro de form de ellos?, ¿En caso de ser así como se hacerlo?

Comment: @develop12 voy a actualizar mi respuesta.

Comment: ahora que ya esta las dos formas listas, y llene los campos al crear un cliente o un vendedor ¿se crea su respectiva cuentas? o ¿tendría que modificar mas?

Comment: Pues algunas cosas que hay que considerar en la implementación son: 1) El código de la forma debe especificar si es para cliente o vendedor. Esto lo podrías hacer pasándolo via params. Después, tendrías que personalizar el controlador de Usuarios (UsersController) y ahí en la acción `create` decirle que si es un "vendedor", entonces además cree una instancia de vendedor y lo mismo para cliente. Este puede ser un ejercicio retador para un principiante en Rails. Sin duda, aprenderías mucho de esta implementación pero tomará tiempo.

Comment: Otro camino, que particularmente no me gusta porque le agrega un paso al usuario, es que TODOS creen una cuenta de usuario de la misma manera, una vez que la cuenta está creada, le preguntes si es Cliente o Vendedor, y eso les muestre una forma específica para crear el tipo de cuenta. Esta implementación sería mucho más sencilla, pero menos amigable para el usuario, en mi opinión. Una ventaja de esta implementación, es que utilizarías la misma relación de modelos User - Vendedor y User-Cliente que ya tienes.